# Lumen mail driver is null issue

Tags: laravel, email, smtp, lumen

I am following this link https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail

here is my bootstrap/app.php code

```
$app->withFacades();
$app->withEloquent();
$app->register(\Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class);
$app->configure('services');
$app->configure('mail');
$app->alias('mailer', Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::class);
$app->alias('mailer', Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer::class);
$app->alias('mailer', Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\MailQueue::class);
```

I run below code as well

```
composer require illuminate/mail
composer update
```

Here is my .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp 
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com 
MAIL_PORT=587 
MAIL_USERNAME=abc@gmail.com 
MAIL_PASSWORD=Abc@12345 
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I installed fresh lumen and i am sure i did not missed anything.

I am getting this error

```
Unable to resolve NULL driver for [Illuminate\Mail\TransportManager].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem. you need to add config file for mail. (config/mail.php)

```
    Just Copy Laravel mail.php config file to lumen root_dir/config/mail.php
```

Reference [THIS LINK](https://medium.com/@edwardsteven/using-lumen-and-laravel-mail-with-mailgun-270415daed37)